# How to count number of documents in aggregate pipeline query?

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go

So basically I am performing a query using an aggregation pipeline.

In one of the stages, I want to count the number of documents **BUT rather than passing the count value to next stage, I'd like to pass the count AND the document(s) that was the input to the count stage.**

**Current workflow:**

1. `$match` stage: get documents whose `sellerId` is a passed in parameter.
2. `$count` stage: count the number of documents found in the `$match` stage.

**Current output:** `{"numDocs": 22}`

**Desired output:** `[{"sellerId": ..., "numDocs": 22}, {"sellerId": ..., "numDocs": 22}, ...]`

The idea is to get the number of documents but to also get the input document that went into the `$count` stage. This could be like the desired output where `numDocs` is appended to each document or is a separate field in the output array.

How can I do this?

**Side note:**I realize this is pretty simple and I could do this use `db.collection.Find()` and `db.collection.Find().Count()` but this is just an example. The real query has many more stages.

Thank you!

Comment: doe's [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4NPAg_F87fN) answer your question?

Comment: @1sina1 It does but with a slight edit: `"_id": "",`. This works but I'm not sure if its "proper" or if its a hackish solution.

Comment: You can use `$group` stage to count and also accumulate all the documents in an array field. Then `$unwind` the array field in the next stage.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$facet`, to calculate counts and store documents in an array, then unwind the array, and set the `numCount` field for each document, something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$facet": {
      "counts": [
        {
          $count: "numDocs"
        }
      ],
      "doc": [
        {
          "$match": {}
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$doc"
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$counts"
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "doc.numCount": "$counts.numDocs",
      
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      counts: 0
    }
  }
]);
```

Here's the playground **[[link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/f6kxjbuRbvL)][1](https://mongoplayground.net/p/f6kxjbuRbvL)**.

Answer (score 0):

the proper way to solve it is to use `$setWindowFields` since `$facet` and `$push` has 16MB size limit

if you have mongodb v5 or higher you can use `$setWindowFields` like this

[test it here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Q6Cb_dwVluD)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $setWindowFields: {
      partitionBy: {
        sellerId: "$sellerId"
      },
      output: {
        numDoc: {
          $sum: 1,
          window: {
            documents: [
              "unbounded",
              "unbounded"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

otherwise you can use `$group` and `$push`

[test it here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4NPAg_F87fN)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$sellerId",
      "numDocs": {
        "$sum": 1
      },
      "docs": {
        "$push": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  }
])
```